# Javascript, while drawing on a canvas setInterval() or increment (i+=) is not working? (New to Javascript/coding)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, setinterval, increment

I am trying to animate the stroke of a box through a canvas from a clicked position on the canvas.

The square is drawing on the canvas where clicked but the p & q values/variables are not updating/incrementing.

When I run a similar function() that doesn't take clientX and clientY as the starting position, it works and draws the square according to the incremented values.

Any help is appreciated.

```js
var clickx = []
var clicky = []

addEventListener("click", clickInfo);
addEventListener("click", drawSquare1);

function clickInfo(){
    j = event.clientX;
    k = event.clientY;
    clickx.push(j)
    clicky.push(k)      
}

function drawS(){
    p = clickx[0]
    q = clicky[0]   
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(p, q, 40, 40);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)";
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    P += 5;
    q += 5;
}

function drawSquare1(){
    setInterval(drawS, 5);
}
```

Comment: There's several things that aren't great here, but the biggest problem is that the incrementing at the end of `drawS` is reset at the next `drawS` interval since it is reassigning them to `clickx[0]` and `clicky[0]`. Also, you have a capital `P` in the incrementing. That's not the error, since those lines don't actually do anything as I've outlined, but figured point it out. Also, every click you run, you are creating a _new_ interval, which is going to get very heavy really quickly. You should look into `clearInterval` and then `requestAnimationFrame` for a more efficient way to time anim.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and thorough answer! I thought that something like that might be happening, but I couldn't figure out how to tell if it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables p and q are not incrementing because they are being reset to the same value (as rgthree has pointed out) each time drawS is called.

To fix this, you should setup as follows...

```
var p = 0,
    q = 0;

function drawS() {

    // increase by 5
    p += 5;
    q += 5;

    //... do stuff
}

function drawSquare1() {

    // initial values before loop
    p = clickx[0];
    q = clicky[0];

    // start loop
    setInterval (drawS, 5);
}
```